# How to access a structure declared in other file using extern keyword in 'c' language

Tags: c

I have 3 files . In one file I declared a structure and in another file which has the main, I am trying to access that structure using extern key word --------

```
//a.c---

include<stdio.h>
extern struct k  ;
extern int c;
int main()
{
  extern int a,b;
  fun1();
  fun2();
  c=10;
  printf("%d\n",c);
  struct k j;
  j.id=89;
  j.m=43;
  printf("\n%d\t%f",j.id,j.m);
}


//1.c

#include<stdio.h>
struct k
{
  int id;
  float m;
}j;

int c;
void fun1()
{
  int a=0,b=5;
  printf("tis is fun1");
  printf("\n%d%d\n",a,b);
}


//2.c--

#include<stdio.h>
struct k
{
  int id;
  float m;
}j;

void fun2()
{
  int a=10,b=4;
  printf("this is fun2()");
  printf("\n%d%d\n",a,b);
}
```

I compiled this code by using `cc a.c 1.c 2.c`
but I am getting error as `storage size of ‘j’ isn’t known`

Comment: Please change the tag. this has nothing to do with c#

Answer (score 2):

```
//a.h---

#include<stdio.h>
#include "1.h"//cannot know its there without including it first.
#include "2.h"
extern struct k;// don't really need to do this and is wrong. 
extern int c;

//a.c
int main()
{
  extern int a,b;//externs i believe should be in the h file?
  fun1();
  fun2();
  c=10;
  printf("%d\n",c);
  struct k *ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct k));//Define our pointer to the struct and make use of malloc.
  //now we can point to the struct, update it and even retrieve.
  ptr->id = 89;
  ptr->m = 43;
  printf("\n%d\t%f" ptr->id,ptr->m);
}


//1.h

#include<stdio.h>
typeof struct k
{
  int id;
  float m;
}j;

//1.c
int c;
void fun1()
{
  int a=0,b=5;
  printf("tis is fun1");
  printf("\n%d%d\n",a,b);
}


//2.h--

#include<stdio.h>
struct k
{
  int id;
  float m;
}j;

//2.c
void fun2()
{
  int a=10,b=4;
  printf("this is fun2()");
  printf("\n%d%d\n",a,b);
}
```

I have edited your code in places so it should see the struct and point to it. Each C file should know have an header h file. When the a.h belonging to your main includes files not only it can see them but should be able to access them. This means it should also know what K is J is alias of K if I remember correctly.

I should know update the struct and retrieve data from it via pointer. If this still doesn't work please post your compiling error and copy n paste the line its crying about.

Answer (score 0):

You have no definition for `struct k` visible from `a.c`. Put the definition in a header file and include it from all three source files.

Answer (score 0):

`struct k` is a description of *how to build* an object. It is not an object. `extern` operates on objects.

Usually `struct` blocks are placed in a header, or `.h` file.

`j` is an object of type `k`. It should be declared `extern` in either `1.c` or `2.c`.

Functions which are used among multiple files, like variables, should be declared before use.

Putting it all together, you might want

```
//a.c---

#include <stdio.h>
#include "k.h" /* contains definition of struct k */

extern int c;
extern k j;

extern void fun1();
extern void fun2();

int main()
{
  extern int a,b;
  fun1();
  fun2();
  c=10;
  printf("%d\n",c);

  j.id=89;
  j.m=43;
  printf("\n%d\t%f",j.id,j.m);
}
```

Comment: in the code in the question, j is a local variable in main.  You have changed it into a global variable (and not defined it).  extern doesn't reserve any storage, it just tells the compiler that there is a j somewhere.

Comment: @Jeremy: Since `j` is a defined as a global in the other files, and `k` was declared `extern`, I assume this is what he wants. Obviously this file is supposed to be compiled with the others. Anyway, it looks like he's just playing around.

Answer (score 0):

Some of your concepts are wrong. Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/what-are-extern-variables-in-c).

To access a variable as extern you have to first define it, which you have not done in your case.

Answer (score -1):

The `extern` modifier changes the *linkage* of the variable that you are declaring or defining.  In C, only variable names can have linkage - not types, like `struct k`.

If you wish to access the internals of a `struct` type, it must be fully defined in the same source file.  The usual way to accomplish this for types that are shared between source files is to place the definition of the `struct` into a header file, which is included with `#include` into each source file.